# make SQL query fail on condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For XYZ reason I need a query to explicitly fail (return error code to connection) if some condition is met (on Snowflake).
Can someone recommend an approach?

Some illustration in pseudo-code:

```
IF 0= ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM XYZ) THEN FAIL
```

Comment: By Fail do you mean - throw an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT IFF(true, 1::number, (1/0)::number);
```

then:

```
IFF(TRUE, 1::NUMBER, (1/0)::NUMBER)
1
```

where-as

```
SELECT IFF(false, 1::number, (1/0)::number);
```

gives:

```
Division by zero
```

Answer (score 3):

I like Simeon's approach, but you may want a custom error message if this is running in a long script. Throwing an error in a JavaScript UDF will allow custom (if untidy) error messages:

```
create or replace function RAISE_ERROR(MESSAGE string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    throw "-->" + MESSAGE + "<--";
$$;

select 
    case (select count(*) from XYZ)
        when 0 then raise_error('My custom error.')
        else 'There are rows in the table'
    end
;
```

If there are no rows in XYZ, it will generate an error message that reads:

> JavaScript execution error: Uncaught --> My custom error <--. in RAISE_ERROR at '
>   throw MESSAGE;' position 4 stackstrace: RAISE_ERROR line: 2

It's not the tidiest of error messages, but it will allow you to embed a custom error message if you need help identifying the error. The arrows should help direct people to the real error message thrown in the stack.